# Is there a way to place the cursor on the QTextEdit when the application starts?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextedit, qtextcursor

I have been trying different ways to place the cursor in the `QTextEdit` when I click open the application. I have a `QTableWidget` in the same application and the first cell of the tabel is highlighted when I open the application. Various examples show (mainly C++) how to retain a cursor after some action is executed but is there a way where the cursor stays in the `QTextEdit` when it opens?

I lack the common understanding of how it works to put the cursor in the `QTextEdit` when the application boots. The code which I tried with no fruition is:

```
cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
self.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.StartOfLine)
```

The other one I tried is:

```
cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
self.moveCursor(QTextCursor.Start)
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Some combination of `pyautogui` and `win32gui` could probably get you there...

Comment: This ["Setting focus on QlineEdit widget"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418905/setting-focus-on-qlineedit-widget) might be helpful to you.

Comment: @HotteShen Thanks for the link! It worked for `QTextEdit` as well.