# How do I automatically change focus between all the line edits in PyQT?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a simple encryption code generator in a program.
When the user enters the first number, I'd like the focus to automatically change to the next line editor (see attached screenshot). I can't find any obvious method which can do this.
I'm new to **PyQT** so I was wondering if anyone knows how this might be possible?

Thanks

[image: Screenshot of my dialogue box]

Comment: Your description is confusing. When do I enter a number or a digit? a digit is {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, etc. and a number is the combination of digits.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to use setFocus() on your QLineEdit. If you upload your code, I might be able to guide you to a solution. Maybe this answer might help you too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418905/setting-focus-on-qlineedit-widget

Comment: @NicholasTJ Something like `self.le1.textEdited.connect(self.le2.setFocus)` for line edits 1, 2, 3?

Comment: @Guimoute Yes :) that is what I have in mind, cheers!

Comment: @eyllanesc apologies for the confusion. The user will enter one digit (0-9) and then it will roll over to the next line editor.

Comment: @NicholasTJ cheers for the help. I'll put my code up in a bit but I'll try the suggestion.

Comment: @unicorn_slayer And what should happen if the user does not enter a digit but for example a letter? o If the user places several letters and then the digit?

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm going to add an input mask so they can only enter one digit 0-9.

Comment: @Guimote Yes this worked, thanks so much :) Thanks Nicholas as well for your help. One other thing though, if I want to correct an entry, and backspace it, the focus will immediately change to the next line editor without giving  me the chance to change the original entry. Is there an easy way around this? Should I look at defining a function which excepts a backspace from changing focus?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize    


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(320, 240))    
        self.setWindowTitle("Keyword") 
        self.anchor = []

        # Line Edit 1
        self.nameLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.nameLabel.setText('#1')
        self.line1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line1.move(80, 20)
        self.line1.resize(200, 32)
        self.nameLabel.move(20, 20)
        self.anchor.append(self.line1)

        # Line Edit 2
        self.nameLabel2 = QLabel(self)
        self.nameLabel2.setText('#2')
        self.line2 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line2.move(80, 60)
        self.line2.resize(200, 32)
        self.nameLabel2.move(20, 60)
        self.anchor.append(self.line2)

        # Line Edit 3
        self.nameLabel3 = QLabel(self)
        self.nameLabel3.setText('#3')
        self.line3 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line3.move(80, 100)
        self.line3.resize(200, 32)
        self.nameLabel3.move(20, 100)
        self.anchor.append(self.line3)

        # Line Edit 4
        self.nameLabel4 = QLabel(self)
        self.nameLabel4.setText('#4')
        self.line4 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line4.move(80, 140)
        self.line4.resize(200, 32)
        self.nameLabel4.move(20, 140)
        self.anchor.append(self.line4)

        # Button
        pybutton = QPushButton('OK', self)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
        pybutton.resize(200,32)
        pybutton.move(80, 200)        

        # Connect
        self.line1.textEdited.connect(lambda state, x=1: self.checkDigit(x))
        self.line2.textEdited.connect(lambda state, x=2: self.checkDigit(x))
        self.line3.textEdited.connect(lambda state, x=3: self.checkDigit(x))
        self.line4.textEdited.connect(lambda state, x=4: self.checkDigit(x))

    def checkDigit(self, data):
        try:
            if (int(self.anchor[data-1].text()) < 10):
                self.anchor[data].setFocus()
        except:
            pass

    def clickMethod(self):
        print("Your four digits are:" + 
              " " + self.line1.text() + 
              " " + self.line2.text() +
              " " + self.line3.text() +
              " " + self.line4.text())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```